# Why is it that my cookie is not getting deleted/unset?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net, cookies

I have a login link that fires a javascript function that calls a logout page.  This is what the logout page consists of:

```
 If Response.Cookies.Count > 0 Then
    Response.Cookies("aLog").Value = Nothing
    Response.Cookies.Clear()
End If
```

Originally I just had cookies.clear in there, but that wasn't working.

Here is the javascript that send the request to the logout page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#logout-link').click(function() {
            if (confirm("Really log out?")) {
                $.cookie('aLog', null);
                location.href = $(this).attr('href');
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

The jQuery function `$.cookie` does not work either.  The cookie is set by ASP.NET, so I figured I could unset it with ASP.NET too but apparently not.  Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Working with cookies in ASP.NET can be a little un-intuitive. To kill a cookie that already lives on the client-side, you have to set its expiration date to sometime in the past, and re-send the client the new cookie. The client browser will update the existing cookie with the new expiration date, and then immediately kill it since it has already passed the expiration date:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["aLog"];
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10);
Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: Ok, so I get to my logout page, it says no cookies are set (request.cookies.count = 0), but when it redirects to the login page the cookie reappears? how annoying.

Comment: re: `AppendCookie`: "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code."  [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendcookie.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Rex said, you should always be setting the ‘path’ of any cookie you use (usually to something like "/"). Otherwise, the visibility of the cookie depends on folder name in the URL, so if you have anything but a flat URL scheme setting and deleting cookies will work very unpredictably.

Comment: Good advice. My problem occurred when setting the cookie with jQuery and then deleting it in a ASP page on another path.